# Why am I getting an error when creating my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a beginner in learning DSA. Getting an error while creating my `ArrayList`

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> List = new ArrayList<>();         //not working, shows error
        ArrayList<Integer> List = new ArrayList<>();    //not working, showing error
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hint: `public class ArrayList` you shouldn't call your classes like something that you just imported and you intend to use in your code.

Comment: In other words, when you're doing `new ArrayList<>();` you're not instantiating a `java.util.ArrayList` like you think you're doing. You're instantiating your own class which is not a generic and is certainly not a `List`.

Comment: you cant have two variables with exact same names

Comment: @user16320675 considering they're declaring the first attempt as a `List` and they're trying using the diamond operator I think it's pretty safe to assume they actually wanted a `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: @user16320675 agreed. That's why it got closed, after all.

Answer (score 2):

You can call your class `ArrayList` but it is a very bad idea. Better to rename it. Second, you have two variables with the same name, which is forbidden. A correct code looks like:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListTest {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Rename class name to something else.

`ArrayList` is a class that came with `java.util` package
Since you imported `java.util.*` , the program can't select this class or the class from `util` package.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> List = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> List = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This still does not compile because of those variables.

Answer (score -3):

You are using the same name, so in the computers storage they would overwrite each other (in theory), if the compiler wouldn't intervene. Just add an indicator to your two variables, like '1' and '2'!

Comment: "so in the computers storage they would overwrite each other (in theory), if the compiler wouldn't intervene" what do you mean?

Comment: They would not overwrite each other in memory. Those 2 variables are explicitly different things because those are individual declarations. But because they have the same name, this simply does not compile. Also, just using `ArrayList` is not specific enough in OP's code.